# In regex capture group, exclude one word

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have this type of url:

```
https://example.com/en/app/893245
https://example.com/ru/app/wq23245
https://example.com/app/8984245
```

I want to extract only word between `com` and `app`

```
https://example.com/en/app/893245 -> en
https://example.com/ru/app/wq23245 -> ru
https://example.com/app/8984245 ->
```

I tried to exclude app from capture group but I don't know how to do it except like this:

`.*com\/((?!app).*)\/app`

Is it possible to something like this but excluding the word app from being captured? `example\.com\/(\w+|?!app)\/`

Rubular link: https://rubular.com/r/NnojSgQK7EuelE

Comment: Try using this [`regex`](https://regex101.com/r/bcp1CC/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a plain regex you may use [**lookarounds**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/(?<=example\.com\/)\w+(?=\/app)/
```

Or, probably better in a context of a URL:

```
/(?<=example\.com\/)[^\/]+(?=\/app)/
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/Tuox4hQDZhwQGB).

[In Ruby](https://ideone.com/YThsGl), you may use

```
strs = ['https://example.com/en/app/893245','https://example.com/ru/app/wq23245','https://example.com/app/8984245']
strs.each { |s|
    p s[/example\.com\/(\w+)\/app/, 1]
}
# => ["en", "ru", nil]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `sed`

`sed -n -f script.sed yourinput.txt`

and inside script.sed:

```
s/.*com\/\(.*\)\/app.*/\1/p
```

Example input:

```
https://example.com/en/app/893245
https://example.com/ru/app/wq23245
https://example.com/app/8984245
```

Example output:

```
$ sed -n -f comapp.sed comapp.txt
en
ru
```